# SASS React.js Undefined Variable

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, sass, frontend

I am new to SASS and React.js. I have scoured many answers on this platform and cannot seem to spot my issue. I have a partial file `_variables.scss` which looks like the following:

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

$raleway-font: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
```

I have imported this into my `App.scss`, along with my other `scss` files like:

```
// Utilities
@import 'styles/variables';

// Stylesheets
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'components/navigationBar/navbar';

@import 'components/main/main';
@import 'components/main/mostRecent/mostRecent';
@import 'components/main/mostRecent/recentCard/recentCard';
@import 'components/main/featuredCard/featuredCard';
```

But when I try to use the variable in any of the files, for example `featuredCard.scss` - I am given the error:

```
SassError: Undefined variable: "$raleway-font".
```

Note that I have used create-react-app, and installed `"node-sass": "^4.14.1"`.
I am importing my files into the `jsx` files with `import './featuredCard.scss';`.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: variables only work in its closure. that means you need import it in evey style block.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are incorrectly importing the address of the variable,

```
@import 'styles/variables';
```

A way to check that you are not correctly placing the address of `variables.scss` , is copying the code in `'components / main / featuredCard / featuredCard';`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

$raleway-font: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

//code featuredCard
```

And comment  `@import 'styles/variables';`